# Is the word "twee" still used in England?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know if the word "twee" is still used in England. If so, in what social context?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=twee

Comment: Wook at dat wabbit hiding behind dat twee.

Comment: Yes 'twee' is still in use in GB, including England. It's not clear to me what you intend by "social context". 'Twee' is still used in journalism of various kinds, with a variety of intended audiences.

Comment: Can you explain why your interest is focused on England and not Australia or Canada for instance? What do you mean by social context? The speakers' class? Their profession? Their education?

Comment: Scroll down until you see a graph mentioning "trends of twee" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/twee.

Comment: What is your context of interest? Often these types of questions generate random responses, and still no one knows whether their response is any close to being a worthwhile answer

Comment: Your name looks like it might be Spanish, and if so, "twee" can be translated as "cursi", as it is used in Spain.

Comment: Personal experience (so a comment rather than answer): widely used in at least northern England (and Scotland, though you didn't ask).  I'd never considered it old-fashioned, so it's strange to be asked if it's *still* used, as if it might have gone out of fashion!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still used mainly in BrE. The Grammarist gives the following notes on usage:

> ***[Twee](https://grammarist.com/usage/twee/)*** means something cloyingly precious, dainty, sweet, quaint, tiny or pretty. ***It carries the connotation of something affected or self-consciously too precious.***
>
> ***Twee is primarily a British English word, through it is gaining ground in North America***. The word twee comes from a simple back-formation from the word tweet, an imitation of a child pronouncing the word sweet.
>
> Currently, the earliest known  use of the word twee was in 1905 in Punch magazine, a satirical British weekly.

Recent usage examples:

> “It could go into saccharine territory and be a bit twee maybe but the thing that cuts that is it look so beautiful and just as you are thinking ‘ahhh’ somebody shouts ‘arsehole’ in Greek. (The MIrror)
>
> Loosening the reins: The Pony Club rebrands for the first time in 87 years in a bid to shake off its twee and tweed image (The Daily Mail)
>
> Now I must really like Kelly because I keep doing that twee hand-over-the-mouth giggle at her jokes. (The Evening Standard)

From Merrian-Webster:

> ***[Twee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twee)*** also originated in baby talk as an alteration of sweet. In the early 1900s, it was a term of affection, but ***nowadays British speakers and writers—and, increasingly, Americans as well—use twee for things that have passed beyond agreeable and into the realm of cloying.***

Comment: Please support the claim that "twee" is still used today in the UK. The article cited by you does not mention current usage or its frequency. The quotes are without dates, so difficult to tell if those headlines were from last year or twenty years ago.